# Java XML how to get the parents and parents attributes of an element?

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML tileset file for my game, like this:

```
<tile id="200">
   <objectgroup draworder="index">
       <object id="10" x="0" y="0" width="18" height="32"/>
   </objectgroup>
</tile>
```

Every time I add something these elements get added every time,
I want to get the `object` element, but there is multiple `object` elements in the file, basically I want to check if the `tile` element has the `id` attribute, if it doesn't then I don't want to get the `object` attributes. If there is no way, to do this, could someone explain a way to differentiate these object from other objects in the file.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am using the `w3c.dom` library and the `xml.parsers` library

Comment: Once you have the object `Node` you can call `getParent()` twice to get to the tile, at which point you can extract its attributes with `getAttributes` and check the id. Or you can do the opposite and get all the tile `Node`s, ignore the ones you don't want and get their children.

Comment: Another way is to use [xpath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.xml.dom/org/w3c/dom/xpath/package-summary.html)

Comment: title improvement